# How do I create WCF EndPointBehaviors in Code rather than the configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configuration

I have the following Xml Configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
         <service name="MyService.MyServiceREST" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1234/MyService/xml"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="xmlBehavior" contract="MyService.IMyService" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="xmlBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I want to implement in C# code rather than using the config.

I cannot figure out who to do the EndPoint with webHttp to expose this service as a REST service.

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(singletonInstance, "http://localhost:1234/MyService/xml");

// Create Meta Behavior
ServiceMetadataBehavior behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
behavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;

serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);

Binding mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();

serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexBinding, "mex");

WSHttpBinding httpBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyService.IMyService), httpBinding, "rest");
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Typically, when doing REST with WCF, you can either use the `<webHttp>` behavior in config, or you can use the `WebServiceHost` class (instead of the "plain vanilla" `ServiceHost`). Using the `WebServiceHost` includes all the necessary tweaks and bits and pieces to make the REST stuff work - no more webHttp behavior needed.

Of course, this means, you need a separate `WebServiceHost` (in `System.ServiceModel.Web`), which hosts a service as REST exclusively. This may or may not be what you're looking for:

```
WebServiceHost webServiceHost = 
    new WebServiceHost(singletonInstance, "http://localhost:1234/MyService/xml");

WebHttpBinding webBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
webServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyService.IMyService), webBinding, "rest");
```

The other option you have is the add a service endpoint to your regular service host, and just configure the web http behavior on that endpoint - endpoint (and service) behaviors are just regular .NET classes, after all, which you can instantiate, and add to the appropriate `Behaviors` collection (on the service or the individual endpoint):

```
WebHttpBinding restBinding = new WebHttpBinding();

ServiceEndpoint restSEP = 
    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyService.IMyService), 
                                   restBinding, "rest");
restSEP.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

Both ways should bring you to your goal, I hope! (or at least get your closer :-)

Comment: I was missing to add the behavior `restSEP.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());` and it worked! Thanks!