# Self Hosted WCF Rest service ERROR : Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported

Tags: wcf, rest, json.net, self-hosting

I have a WCF Rest service that's self hosted. It works fine until I decided I have to use JToken ([Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm)). I then got the error :

```
Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.
```

I've seen all the answers from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069176/getting-recursive-collection-data-contract-when-referencing-a-wcf-service-with), this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542371/error-adding-service-reference-type-is-a-recursive-collection-data-contract-whi) and others. The fact is, I'm hosting my services within an internal program (in the company where I work, can't show it :-( ). I'm doing it exactly like it's self hosted, but the implementations and the interfaces of my services aren't as a WCF Service Library, just Class Library, so I can't access the menu they're talking about in the answers (where there's : "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies").

I couldn't find any solution and I would like to use JToken.

Here's my service contract :

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ISearchService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "search/")]
        List<Client> SearchClient(JToken jsonBody);
    }
```

My hosting is done like in this post : [How do I create WCF EndPointBehaviors in Code rather than the configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142712/how-do-i-create-wcf-endpointbehaviors-in-code-rather-than-the-configuration) (I had to do it without a configuration file).

Hope my question is clear.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like you are using `DataContractJsonSerializer` to deserialize your JSON.  Unfortunately, it doesn't support `JToken`.  Try switching to Json.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792785/replace-wcf-default-json-serialization or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153628/replace-wcf-built-in-javascriptserializer-with-newtonsoft-json-net-json-serializ.